# Jquery: getting CSS or style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I guess there is something obviously wrong with this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("homepage-mobile-cat1"); 
console.log(elem);

var test1 = elem.style("margin-left");
var test2 = elem.css("margin-left");
```

This returns `elem.style` or `elem.css` function does not exist.

The output of console.log is

```
<div id="homepage-mobile-cat1" class="container homepage-mobile-cat red-background-mobile" style="margin-left: 0 !important;">
  <a href="http://www.example.co.uk/literacy/">
    <div class="CSSTable homepage-cat-text" style=""><p><span style="width:80%; display:block !important;margin:0 auto;">  Literacy Resources</span></p></div> <!-- CSSTable homepage-cat-text -->
  </a>        
</div>
```

Comment: You should be reading a lot about these methods and how this tasks are to be achieved....

Comment: Use elem.style.marginLeft; and there is no method elem.css exists in javascript

Comment: you are trying to mix javascript with jquery. in javascript :- elem.style.marginLeft and in jquery it is $("#homepage-mobile-cat1").css("margin-left")

Answer (score 2):

`style` is not a function in javascript.`elem.style.marginLeft` will give the value

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("homepage-mobile-cat1");
var test1 = elem.style.marginLeft;
console.log(test1)
```

```html
<div id="homepage-mobile-cat1" class="container homepage-mobile-cat red-background-mobile" style=" margin-left: 0 !important;">
  <a href="http://www.example.co.uk/literacy/">
    <div class="CSSTable homepage-cat-text" style="">
      <p><span style="width:80%; display:block !important;margin:0 auto;">  Literacy Resources</span></p>
    </div>
    <!-- CSSTable homepage-cat-text -->
  </a>
  </div>
```

`css` is a jquery method &  it will work with jquery object

```js
console.log($("#homepage-mobile-cat1").css("margin-left"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="homepage-mobile-cat1" class="container homepage-mobile-cat red-background-mobile" style="margin-left: 0 !important;">
  <a href="http://www.example.co.uk/literacy/">
    <div class="CSSTable homepage-cat-text" style="">
      <p><span style="width:80%; display:block !important;margin:0 auto;">  Literacy Resources</span></p>
    </div>
    <!-- CSSTable homepage-cat-text -->
  </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try jquery:

```
alert($('#homepage-mobile-cat1').css('margin-left'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("homepage-mobile-cat1"); 


// You can use this method to calculate the style
var test1 = window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue("margin-left");
console.log(test1);


//Or directly get the value from style. But this requires the property value to be already assigned to the style. If not, use the method above.
console.log(elem.style.marginLeft);

//Or alternatively, you can use JQuery
console.log($("#homepage-mobile-cat1").css("margin-left"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="homepage-mobile-cat1" class="container homepage-mobile-cat red-background-mobile" style="



     margin-left: 0 !important;"><a href="http://www.example.co.uk/literacy/">
      <div class="CSSTable homepage-cat-text" style=""><p><span style="width:80%; display:block !important;margin:0 auto;">  Literacy Resources</span></p></div> <!-- CSSTable homepage-cat-text --></a>



      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `elem.style.marginLeft`.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("homepage-mobile-cat1"); 
console.log(elem);

var test1 = elem.style.marginLeft;
console.log(test1);
```

```html
<div id="homepage-mobile-cat1" class="container homepage-mobile-cat red-background-mobile" style="margin-left: 0 !important;">
  <a href="http://www.example.co.uk/literacy/">
    <div class="CSSTable homepage-cat-text" style=""><p><span style="width:80%; display:block !important;margin:0 auto;">  Literacy Resources</span></p></div> 
  <!-- CSSTable homepage-cat-text -->
  </a>

</div>
```